# How to store two tables in Room Persistence Library of same data Type?

Tags: android, database, database-design, android-room

For example, Here is the data type,

```
User {
    String name;
    String lastName;
}
```

Now I'm storing this User class with Room and retrieving the list of all users with Dao

```
LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers();
```

Now I want to add the **Delete User** functionality to it. And I also wanted to store all the deleted users in a separate table so that I can show them in a different place/Activity.
But I couldn't able to figure out what could be the better approach for this. Since the data type of deleted user is the same as User.
One way is to add an additional field into the User class and filter the list every time before displaying

```
User {
    String name;
    String lastName;
    boolean deleted = false;
}
```

I just have to change the boolean value `deleted`  when I delete the User object.

But I don't want to filter the list every time instead I want to store this deleted user in a separate table and this way I can retrieve the list of User and list of Deleted User much faster and save the time while filtering.

So how can I do this or is this the right way of achieving this delete functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two questions:

> How to store two tables in Room Persistence Library of same data Type?

This question from your post' title

and

> What is better - to store two tables or just one but to filter it?

I think this is the core of your question.

So,

**1. How to store two tables in Room Persistence Library of same data Type?**

The answer is simple. You should make two separate Room's entities, two separate DAO's for them (though you can use just one) and after deleting user you should in transaction delete it from one table and insert into another.

**2. What is better - to store two tables or just one but to filter it?.**

Of course, the answer is opinionated. You should consider all PROs and CONTRAs and make your choice.

Why `to filter` is better?

- `User` and `DeletedUser` essentially are the same, they just has different status.
- You don't need to duplicate the same fields in two tables. Otherwise you (and another developers who will maintain your app) should hold in mind that each change in `User` table (adding some field etc.) should be followed by the same changes in `DeletedUser`.
- As usual Room's entities have `id`-s and they could be used in another entities as foreign key. As such you can't use `User`'s id as foreign key, since after deleting it from `User` you can lose data in entities that are attached to it. In general, if `User` table is planned to have connections with another tables in app, then using separate `DeletedUser` is a bad way.

Why `two tables` is better?

- As you've mentioned the filtered query might be slower. How much slower? That depends. For small tables (with up to 1,000 rows or even 10,000 rows) I guess you may not to see the difference. Still if you have some edge-case (enormous table) and struggle for performance really makes sense, you can choose that way.

P.S. Using Livedata in Room filtered result will be updated for you. So if you decide to use single table and one of the users in the table turns into `delete`-state, result will be updated without any special `refresh`-calls.